# Geometry nodes after Array

Tags: modifiers, drivers, procedural, geometry-nodes

I am exploring the new geometry nodes, my goal is to create a very simple procedural tree: a brown cone and a few green pyramids on top of it . I would like to apply random variations to the pyramids like rotation, scale, color later maybe subdiv and deformation as well. For now I just work with cubes.

Geometry nodes seem not to support array-like operations so far (Blender 2.93), so I added an array modifier in front of it. However, when I use the *Random Float* node, I have no idea how to set the `seed` individually for each object copy that was created by the *Array* modifier. I tried to make the `seed` a custom parameter of the geometry nodes modifier and use a driver to set a unique value for each instance. However, that plan failed since `self` in the driver expression points to the modifier, not to the object so I cant get something like an index out from the *Array* modifier, also connecting the driver to `location.z` related to the original cube, not to its modified version.

My second try was to use the *Bounding Box* node and get the `min.z` to feed it into the seed. This failed as well, since it also seems to relate to the original object before the application of *Array*.

Both my attempts are captured in the following screenshot. The spreadsheet shows values of the driver (`location.z`) the random rotation is seeded by the `min.z` of the bounding box.
[image]

So I am wondering, how to access the array instance index or similar data inside the geometry nodes?

Comment: At the moment it is not possible. What I would explore though is using the UVs offset parameter in the Array modifier, and use the UVs information in the GN tree. Since you are only arraying along Z axis it would also be really easy to separate each instance by its Z coordinate. Will not work for more complicated models or intricate arrays though

Comment: you can solve this by other "workarounds" but with geometry nodes. Are you open for such solutions?

Comment: @Gorgious that is an interesting hack, I will try it and let you know. Still, I would wish for a proper solution offered by Geometry Nodes.

Comment: @Chris Thank you, but I am only interested in exploring the procedural power of Blender. In that sense, I could easily create a script that would replace the Array modifier and create unique objects with IDs. But that does not align with the geometry nodes workflow I envision.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find a way! There is a mesh primitive node called `Line`. I can use it as a 1D array. Unfortunately I didn't find a way how to convert a float to an integer to feed its `count` slot, so I switched to `end points` combined with `resolution`.

I can also easily extract the `index` property from the line vertices, just by using an `attribute separate xyz` of the vertex `z` position.

So here is the relevant part of my setup (lower left of the screenshot). The node graph of the tree already grew large as I have quite some variations inside.[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Isolin's way seems much more in the spirit.. but here goes with a follow-up of @Gorgious' comment. This just gets a random-per-array-element attribute on to all the array-object's vertices.

[image]

- Setting a U offset of 1 in the *Array* modifier
- `floor`ing the split-out U of the 'UV Map' attribute gives you an index per array element, on all vertices
- That index can be randomized by using it to look up into some kind of noise texture: (clouds.. it's *always* clouds :) )
- The random value per array element can be put through some kind of function to modify other attributes.

[image]

(Left: original .. Right: with GN )